# Angular-Material-Datepicker: value-problem with customized picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am using the "Datepicker with custom formats" from https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview.

I did 2 changes.

- Removed FormControl and use Date with [(ngModel)]
- Show date.getDay in the template

Here is my stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnmjnv

If I use the datepicker and set a new date then the new value of date would be not a Date anymore.
getDay fails.

> _co.date.getDay is not a function

That is not the case if I put my changes in the datepicker without custom formats. The problem occurs as long I have the special format in place.

```
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
{provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
```

Put both lines in a comment and it will work. But then the format of the date is standard and not customized.

Whats the problem here? How to have custom formats and a Date?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use MomentDateAdapter your date become Moment object on input change, so you should wrap date `date = moment(new Date (2000,11,24));` and use moment methods `{{date.date()}}`

You need import a MatMomentDateModule for the MomentDateAdapter to work correctly.

Comment: "import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';"

would not make is work.

Comment: BTW if you add MatMomentDateModule for the MomentDateAdapter you should add moment and your bundle size is about 300k more :(